# How to make testing-library debug output more compact (but not minified)?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, testing-library

The output from testing library Automatic Logging https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#automatic-logging usually contains a lot of new lines that make the output hundreds or thousands of lines long (yes, I'm using a huge `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT`), which makes it quite hard to find the relevant part. It looks for example like this:
[image: example_output]b

I assume the DOM output has all the new lines, because they are in the source code of my Vue components. One way would be to change my components, but I don't want to do that as it's formatted according to rules from https://eslint.vuejs.org/

I see that https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#prettydom has "Options" that link to https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/pretty-format#usage-with-options, but I don't see any relevant option in there and I don't know how to pass those to the automatic logging.

Is there a way to have some control over how is the HTML formatted? For example, I would like to avoid new lines in an element opening tag if it has only one attribute. E.g. in the example screenshot, it would merge the first three lines into one: `<span class="organisation-details">`?